# exclui uma pasta localmente mais nao consigo salvar a mudança remotamente no github "Everything up-to-date"

Tags: git, github

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

exclui a pasta, usei git add e commitei, ele detectou as mudanças no commit mas mesmo assim quando vou dar um push no master ele diz que está "Everything up-to-date"
o que to fazendo errado ?

Comment: Tentou forçar o push?

Comment: qual a diferença pra esse push forçado ? ele re-escreve todas as pastas ? tem alguma maneira de só apagar a pasta q eu quero que apague ?

Comment: usei push origin --force <branch> e funcionou. obrigado

Comment: Sim, o repo vai ser recriado. De nada brother, mas não é normal precisar do --force. E parece que no commit diz "0 deletions". Se acontecer de novo manda aí que a gente investiga.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Git não versiona pastas vazias, portanto só a ação de excluir o conteúdo da pasta já fará com que ela saia do versionamento.

Criei um repo com um arquivo na raiz e dois arquivos em uma pasta:

[image: A imagem mostra o conteúdo do repositório]

No Git não basta excluir os arquivos diretamente no sistema de arquivos ou no disco, é necessário fazer isso por um comando de exclusão:

```
git rm .\files\*.txt
```

O comando acima exclui todos os aquivos de extensão txt da pasta files. Repare que eu não fiz a exclusão da pasta, nem diretamente no dico.

Em seguida eu fiz o commit dessa alteração. A imagem abaixo mostra o commit e a listagem de arquivos no repositório, mostrando que a pasta não existe mais.

[image: Comando de exclusão e commit da alteração]

Para enviar as alterações para o Github é só utilizar o comando:

```
git push origin master
```

Assumindo que o seu remote é origin e a branch é a master.

Não é necessário utilizar o *force*, pois se não tem inconsistência entre o repositório remoto e o local, exclusão de arquivos ou pastas não necessitam de permissões especiais.